# Change name of power point files

Tags: vba, file, powerpoint

I would like to change name of Powerpoint files.

I have my ppt file name like : 1.pptx, 2.pptx inside a folder.

I would like to change this name with a corporate title.

How can I proceed to change the name of Powerpoint files in VBA ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: this might help https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2339-excel-rename-files-in-a-folder.html     and     http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?57146-VBA-Code-for-Searching-Renaming-files-in-a-folder

Comment: @tomerpacific The first answer in the post you link to is incorrect; scroll further down and you'll see that someone else (the OP in fact) has found and replied with the correct answer (same as Uri's answer here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming a file in `vba` is done with the `Name` statement

```
Name "old.pptx" As "new.pptx"
```

Note that this would fail if you are trying to rename an open document or if your code doesn't have the right permissions